# Unable to show JQuery datepicker on my php page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I followed the source code on Jquery page to get a datepicker for my php page, but I cant get the calendar out. I think the Jquery is not loading for this page, can anyone tell me why? Thanks you

Here is my source code: I have my own designs for class element.

```
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">

     <title>Admin</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navi.css" media="screen" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
$(".box .h_title").not(this).next("ul").hide("normal");
$(".box .h_title").not(this).next("#home").show("normal");
$(".box").children(".h_title").click( function() {   $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(); });
    });
    </script>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
   });
  </script>

 </head>
 <script>
 function validateForm()
 {
 var x=document.forms["my_form"]["title"].value;
 var y=document.forms["my_form"]["author"].value;
 var z=document.forms["my_form"]["keywords"].value;
 var type=document.forms["my_form"]["category"].value;

 if (x=="" || y=="" || z =="" || type=="")
 {
 alert("Please fill in the required fields");
 return false;
 }



 }
 </script>


 <body>


  <div class="wrap">
<div id="header">
    <div id="top">
        <div class="left">
            <p>Welcome, <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['login']?>      </strong> [ <a href="logout.php">logout</a> ]</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="upp"><a href="#">Manage Content</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>&#8250; <a href="admin.php">Admin  Home</a></li>
                    <li>&#8250; <a href="viewPosts.php">Manage Posts</a></li>   
                    <li>&#8250; <a href="changePass.php">Manage User</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="h_title">&#8250; Manage content</div>
            <ul id="home">
                    <li class="b1"><a class="icon view_page" href="admin.php">Admin Home</a></li>   
                <li class="b2"><a class="icon report" href="viewPosts.php">Add Posts</a></li>                   
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="h_title">&#8250; Category</div>
            <ul id="home">
                <?php 
                        include("includes/connect.php"); 

                        $sql = "SELECT  post_type, COUNT(*) AS num FROM post WHERE post_status ='New' GROUP BY post_type";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql);
                        while($Cat_row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        $type =$Cat_row['post_type'];
                        $number = $Cat_row['num'];
                ?>
                <li class="b2"><a class="icon category" href="postType.php?cat=<?php echo $type?>"><?php echo $type." (".$number.")"?></a></li> 
                <?php }?>           
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <div class="h_title">&#8250; Archives</div>
                <ul id="home">
                <?php
                    include("includes/connect.php"); 
                    $sql_arc ="SELECT post_type, COUNT(*) AS  numb FROM post WHERE post_status='Old' GROUP BY post_type";
                    $result_arc = mysql_query($sql_arc);
                    while($Arc_row=  mysql_fetch_array($result_arc)){
                    $type_arc =$Arc_row['post_type'];
                    $number_arc = $Arc_row['numb'];
                ?>
                <li class="b1"><a class="icon config" href="postArchive.php?type=<?php echo $type_arc?>"><?php echo $type_arc." (".$number_arc.")"?></a></li>
                    <?php }?>       
                </ul>                   
        </div>



    </div>





    <div id="main">

        <div class="full_w">
            <div class="h_title">Add new Posts</div>

            <form method="post" action="viewPosts.php" name="my_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                <div class="element">
                    <label >Title <span class="red">*</span></label> 
                    <input type="text" name="title" class="text err" />
                </div>

                <div class="element">
                    <label>Author <span class="red">*</span></span></label>
                    <input type="text"  name="author" class="text err" />
                </div>

                <div class="element">
                    <label>Keywords <span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" name="keywords" class="text err" />
                </div>

                <div class="element">
                 <input type="text" id="datepicker">
                </div>  

                <div class="element">
                    <label>Category <span class="red">*</span></label>
                    <select name="category" class="err">
                        <option value="">-- select category</option>
                        <option value="Class">Class</option>
                        <option value="Facilities">Facilities</option>
                        <option value="Services">Services</option>
                        <option value="Announcement">Announcement</option>
                        <option value="Promotions">Promotions</option>
                        <option value="News">News</option>
                        <option  value="Uncategorized">Uncategorized</option>
                    </select>
                </div>






                <div class="element">

                    <label for="content">Page content <span>(required)</span></label>
                    <textarea id="editor1" name="content" class="textarea" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
                 <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.

            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
            {
            // Load the German interface.
            language: ''
            });
        </script>
                <div class="entry">
                      <button type="submit" name="submit"   class="add">Save Post</button> 
                      <button class="cancel" type="reset" >Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="left">
        <p>NUS Staff Club Admin Panel</p>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
     include("includes/connect.php");
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $post_title = $_POST['title'];
     $post_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $post_author = $_POST['author'];
$post_keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
$post_type  = $_POST['category'];
$post_content = $_POST['content'];
$post_status = 'New';

    //  $post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    //  $image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


  /*if(empty($post_title) || empty($post_author) || empty($post_keywords) ||    empty($post_type) || empty($post_content) ){
 exit();
 }*/
  //    else{
  //    move_uploaded_file($image_temp,"../image/$post_image");

$insert_query = "insert into post  (post_title,post_date,post_author,post_keywords,post_type,post_content,post_status) values ('$post_title','$post_date','$post_author'
,'$post_keywords','$post_type','$post_content','$post_status')";

if(mysql_query($insert_query)){
echo "<script>alert('Post has been pushlished successfully')</script>";
     echo "<script>window.open('admin.php','_self')</script>";
}
else{   echo "<script>alert('failed')</script>";}
   //      }

    }

    ?>
    <?php }?>
```

Comment: First load jQuery then load it's UI library.

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: By changing the order of script tags!

Comment: Does the browser console fire any errors?

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: sry, the script tags were in correct, I copied them into wrong place. Now the tags are in correct positions but still not loading

Comment: Its working code, show us exactly what you have tried?

Comment: not sure if you want to read it, here is the source code for this page

Comment: It is not working might be because you are calling jQuery twice (i.e. jquery 1.7.2.min.js and jquery 1.9.1.js). Just call 1 jquery.js only

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your element before it's created...

**replace**

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

**by**

```
$().ready(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
})
```

;

Comment: sry, It does not work. I try to put it on a test page and it works. I thinkg it has sth to do with my template